# Why won't my array print out correctly?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a simple program using the code below to make a single dimensional array that you can then call a value from using the index numbers.  I am using [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) as my compiler.  Whenever I try to debug or run the program, the full array prints out as this: `[I@1fa8d3b`.

```
class Array    
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] MyArray = new int[] {15, 45, 34, 78, 65, 47, 90, 32, 54, 10};
    System.out.println("The full array is:");
    System.out.println(MyArray);
    System.out.println("The 4th entry in the data is: " + MyArray[3]);
}
}
```

The correct data entry prints out when it is called though.  I have tried to look for answers online as to what I should do, but I could not find anything that actually works.  I am just starting to learn Java so there could be a very simple answer to this that I am just overlooking.  If anyone has any ideas, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Arrays have the default implementation of `equals()`, `hashCode()`, and `toString()`.

Answer (score 8):

Java is an object oriented language. When you are calling `System.out.print(MyArray);` in Java you are actually printing <del>the address of the object on the heap in memory</del> the toString code from it's parent class `Object`, the code is shown below contributed by the comment from EngFouad, sorry for misspeaking. The weird String you see printed out is the reference the computer uses to find your data when you ask for something associated with the variable `MyArray`.

As stated by the other answers, to print out the data of your object you can use the `Array` class's built in `.toString()` method. This will print the data from the object instead of just the object reference.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MyArray);
```

**Correction**
Actually it is toString() of the class Object: getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()). – Eng.Fouad

Mistake above was corrected thanks for the comments, hate to give the wrong information. I misunderstood it myself. Here is the API reference to see the code:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Comment: Actually it is `toString()` of the class `Object`: `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`.

Comment: It definitely is not the address on the heap!

Comment: @Eng.Fouad and MarkRotteveel thanks for the corrections, making an edit now. I misspoke, I thought it was the address from my education.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MyArray));
```

In order to [print the array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409795/1651233).
In your case you used the default [Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) implementation, which is not so informative...

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MyArray));
```

[API Reference: Arrays.toString(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29)

Comment: It worked, thanks! I was correct in thinking that it was a very simple fix.

Comment: @user2320169 This is not a fix, it is a java language feature. Learn what the `Object` `toString()` method does.

Answer (score 0):

to print the array you need to use the loop. for example:

```
for (int i: MyArray){
System.out.print(i + " ")}
```